# Getting a new datatime by offsetting a lapse in the unit of second from a fixed constant datetime

Tags: python, pandas, date

Given a fix datetime `'2019-01-15 7:00:00'`, the objective is to create a new datatime based on an offset value under the column `(offset, '')` . The unit of the offset value is in term of `second`.

The expected output is given in the column `time`

```
      (offset,'' )  time
0             0  2019-01-15 7:00:00
1            20  2019-01-15 7:00:20
2            40
3            60  2019-01-15 7:01:00
4            80
...         ...
4315      86300
4316      86320
4317      86340
4318      86360
4319      86380
[4320 rows x 1 columns]
```

My impression this can be achieved via

```
pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-15 7:00:00']).add(pd.to_timedelta(df[('lapse','')],unit='s'))
```

However, the compiler return an error

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'add'
```

May I know how to resolve issue?

The full code to reproduce the above issue is as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
increment=20
max_val=86400
# Elapse unit in second
aran=np.arange(0,max_val,increment).astype(int)
df=pd.DataFrame(aran,columns=[('lapse','')])

df['time']=pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-15 7:00:00']).add(pd.to_timedelta(df[('lapse','')],unit='s'))
```

Comment: Pass the date as a str rather than list and use the `+` operator: `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-15 7:00:00') + pd.to_timedelta(df[('lapse','')],unit='s')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `origin` and `unit='s'` parameters:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[('lapse','')], origin='2019-01-15 7:00:00', unit='s')
print (df)
      (lapse, )                time
0             0 2019-01-15 07:00:00
1            20 2019-01-15 07:00:20
2            40 2019-01-15 07:00:40
3            60 2019-01-15 07:01:00
4            80 2019-01-15 07:01:20
        ...                 ...
4315      86300 2019-01-16 06:58:20
4316      86320 2019-01-16 06:58:40
4317      86340 2019-01-16 06:59:00
4318      86360 2019-01-16 06:59:20
4319      86380 2019-01-16 06:59:40

[4320 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your timestamp as a `str` instead of `list` and use the `+` operator:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-15 7:00:00') + pd.to_timedelta(df[('lapse','')],unit='s')
```

[out]

```
      (lapse, )                time
0             0 2019-01-15 07:00:00
1            20 2019-01-15 07:00:20
2            40 2019-01-15 07:00:40
3            60 2019-01-15 07:01:00
4            80 2019-01-15 07:01:20
...         ...                 ...
4315      86300 2019-01-16 06:58:20
4316      86320 2019-01-16 06:58:40
4317      86340 2019-01-16 06:59:00
4318      86360 2019-01-16 06:59:20
4319      86380 2019-01-16 06:59:40

[4320 rows x 2 columns]
```